# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" NullPointerException error in Swing

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe

I'm start creating a desktop application using Swing and I'm totally new in it. As i didn't find any error in syntax or structure but it throws error. It is just a event demo program.

```
package testEvent;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class EventDemo {

    JLabel jlab;
    EventDemo(){
        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("An Event Example");
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setSize(220,90);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton jbtnAlpha = new JButton("Alpha");
        JButton jbtnBeta = new JButton("Beta");
        jbtnAlpha.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                jlab.setText("Alpha was Pressed.");
            }
        });

        jbtnBeta.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                jlab.setText("Beta was Pressed.");
            }
        });

        jfrm.add(jlab);     
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Create the Frame on Event Dispatching thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new EventDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Throws below error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at testEvent.EventDemo.<init>(EventDemo.java:40)
at testEvent.EventDemo$3.run(EventDemo.java:49)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)*
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: As with any NPE (NullPointerException), the key is the line that throws it since a variable on that line that you are trying to dereference is null. So which line is it? Which line is `EventDemo.java:40`? Also, more important than getting a specific solution is to learn the general techniques on debugging NPE's -- 1) find the offending line, 2) check the variables on the line to see which one(s) are null, 3) trace back into the code to see *why* it is null, 4) then fix it.

Comment: BTW - change `jfrm.setSize(220,90);
...
    jfrm.add(jlab);` to `... jfrm.pack(); // sizes frame to content

    jfrm.add(jlab);`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks to give deep details now i can understand NPE lil bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialise the JLabel jlab. Something like the following should do.

```
JLabel jlab = new JLabel();
```